# Was a user who posted a comment as answer assisted in commenting by a moderator?

Tags: support, comments, moderation

Recently, I found a user that had a reputation under 50, so he couldn't comment. Instead, he put the comment into an answer, which people shouldn't do. I flagged the answer. After I rechecked, one of the admins or moderators deleted the "answer" and put it into a comment which had the author as the person under 50 reputation. Did a moderator do that? Can moderators do it? Or was it some community admin?

Comment: Thanks for asking here and thanks for noticing the comment that needed maintenance. You're now a moderator of the site too! Just missing some of the advanced tools...

Comment: me? Don't you need to be elected for moderation, or have 20k reputation for some limited moderation?

Comment: [Everyone's a moderator!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

Comment: Just realized. Flagging, edits are moderation. Though less advanced. More rep, more trust...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, moderators can change an answer into a comment and attach it to the question (or any other answer) within the same question thread. Usually we use this exactly in the situation you mention (low rep user asking a clarification question).